# How to implement a loading screen or multithreading in iOS?

Tags: ios, multithreading, loading

I have a login-screen.
After the user enters his credentials, he clicks on "Login" to login.
Now in the background with the login there will be a load of a few things, so it need around 3 seconds to display the next view.

How to solve that the screen is not freezing within this 3 seconds?

I had the idea to solve this by a loading screen (Typical for iPhone Apps) or shange the clicked button to "Try to Login...", so the user is not only thinking "has my click worked or should I click again"... 
I hope its understandable...

Whats to do?

Comment: 1 quest: Are your credentials uitextfields inside a uitableviewcell?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use MBProgressHUD its show an indicator with label if you want like "loading" for example and disable the user action on the view also its easy to use and has a good/simple interface.

you can find it on this [link](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)